# read Colander Schema from a config file or database

Tags: python, schema, pyramid, colander

I googled for a while but I could not find reference on how to retrieve a Colander Schema from a config file or from a database. I think this is not difficult to implement but I might have overlooked something. Maybe somebody has done or seen something like that and might share some insights.

Here a sample for a Colander Schema:

```
class PageSchema(colander.MappingSchema):
    title = SchemaNode(String(),
                       title='Page title',
                       description='The title of the page',
                       )
    description  = SchemaNode(String(),
                              title='A short description', 
                              description='Keep it under 60 characters or so',
                              missing = u'',
                              validator=colander.Length(max=79)
                              )
    body = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String(),
                               description='Tell the world',
                               missing = u'')
```

Answer (score 1):

As micheal said, it might not be supported. If you really need it. Here is some pointers.

Save your schema in a database by name for example: "PageSchema". Save all of its record in the database with all the needed parameters.

You'd have to do something like that:

```
for row in rows:
    attrinbutes[row['name']] = build_attribute(row)

schemas[schema_name] = type(schema_name, (colander.MappingSchema,), attributes)
exec('%s = schemas[schema_name]' % schema_name)
```

In other words, it loads all attributes and build a class using the type operator. That kind of task is pretty simple and should work as good as the habitual `class` syntax. The `exec` call is just to push the name in locals. You could probably use `locals()[schema_name] = schmea` or even other scopes.

That way you can load schemas from anywhere if needed. You could build yourself a factory like:

- `schemas.get('PageSchema')` that would return a schema if possible or None if not present.

That's pretty much it!

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by colander. The one thing I know of in this area is the "limone" package which does the opposite. It is able to generate arbitrary python objects *from* a colander schema.

Answer (score 0):

[ColanderAlchemy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ColanderAlchemy) may do what you need.  It takes SQLAlchemy objects and generates a Colander schema from them.  However, generating from an SQLAlchemy object isn't exactly "from a database".